# bootstrap 3 push/pull issue

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am learning to use bootstrap 3

I have a problem with using push and pull
Normally the rows are centered
but When i use push/pull the row gets aligned left, and go off the left of the screen if the browser is not fullscreen.

why is this

code bellow

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
    <title>Bootstrap 3 Playabout</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="bootstrap.js"></script>

    <style>
    .a
    {
        background-color:green;
    }

    .b
    {
        background-color:blue;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 a col-lg-push-4">One</div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-8 b col-lg-pull-8">Two</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: create a bootply to show the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch the push/pull numbers like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 a col-lg-push-8">One</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-8 b col-lg-pull-4">Two</div>
```

[Working Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/120119)

Comment: well, as I said you simply have to switch the numbers. If you have a `col-md-4`, you need to use a `col-lg-push-8`not `col-lg-push-4`.. ;)